# Implementing a data structure to hold a stream of chars

Tags: c, data-structures

Given a stream of chars (or an unknown large number of chars), I would like to implement a data structure to hold these chars, with the following functionality and properties.

### Functionality

1. Insert a new char (at the end)
2. Print all existing chars in their received order
3. Delete chars in a certain range (not necessarily from the end)

### Properties

(For `N` - current number of chars).

**Complexity:**

1. Insertion - `O(1)`
2. Printing - As fast as possible, but not more than `O(N)`
3. Deletion - About `O(log(N))`

**Memory:**

Proportional and not much larger than `N`.

### Current Solutions

> - Array - Deletion too complex.
> - Linked list - Deletion is fast but finding the indexes in the required range is complex.
> - Hash table  - Couldn't think of an implementation with an easy re-balancing method.

I believe the solution will be with some linked list with a fast indexing array but updating such array always ended up complex.

---

Implementation will be done in C, but any pseudo code that doesn't use any special functions will do the trick.

Can you think of any implementation that fulfills these properties?

Comment: @melpomene possible with arrays but O(N) will be fine to start with. Would like it faster if possible tho

Comment: printing in smaller O(N) will **not** be possible. Even with all characters contiguously in memory, so you can just use a pre-made printing function, therefore hiding the complexity from your code, this function will have to read all the characters. You could assume it can print/copy several characters at once, e.g. 8, then you'll still have O(N/8) which is equivalent to O(N).

Comment: and yes, it isn't a stream. An unbuffered stream wouldn't store anything, a buffered stream would have a standard **queue** as a buffer (which doesn't allow deletion). With your requirements, I'd go for an array of dynamic size. Deletion can be implemented using `memmove()` in C. (this will be smaller O(N), as you're only moving part of your data. Not sure I can do the math here, but might very well be O(ln N) in the mean)

Comment: I'm afraid your complexity requirements are contradictory. Although a mere `char*` with appropriate dedicated functions will do the work, in C it will always be lightning fast, even with `O(n)` complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a simple dynamic array should give you the properties you want:

- Printing is trivially `O(N)`. You have to copy all characters, and as they are contiguous in memory, no extra complexity is needed. See also my comment.
- Appending a character (this is not insertion, as you say it's always at the end) is `O(1)`. Let's assume you allocate memory for every single character: Then you'll have overhead for this allocation with each call, but it's constant. In practice, you will speed up your code by allocating chunks instead: You'll have the constant overhead only every e.g. 1024th call, but this still means a constant overhead.
- Deletion is a bit more complex. You'll have to update your counter of course, but this is constant. Then you'll have to move existing data. In the worst case (deleting just the first character), this means moving `N-1` characters -> `O(N)`. In the best case (deleting just the last character), it means no moving at all, so just `O(1)` for updating the counter. As already commented, I won't do the math here (you'd have to consider each possible combination of start and length for the sequence you want to delete), but the result will be below `O(N)`.
- Memory complexity is the number of characters stored, plus two size variables (count and capacity) plus some unused space between 0 and the size of your chunk for allocation. Seems to match, it's proportional and close to `N`.

---

Possible data structure in C:

```
# define CHUNKSIZE 1024

struct container
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t count;
    char *content;
};

struct container *create_container(void)
{
    struct container *c = malloc(sizeof *c);
    if (c)
    {
        c->capacity = CHUNKSIZE;
        c->count = 0;
        c->content = malloc(CHUNKSIZE);
        if (!c->content)
        {
            free(c);
            c = 0;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

void delete_container(struct container *c)
{
    if (!c) return;
    free(c->content);
    free(c);
}
```

---

"Insertion":

```
int container_append(struct container *c, char chr)
{
    if (c->count == c->capacity)
    {
        char *newcontent = realloc(c->content, c->capacity + CHUNKSIZE);
        if (!newcontent) return -1;
        c->capacity += CHUNKSIZE;
        c->content = newcontent;
    }
    c->content[c->count++] = chr;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Printing:

```
void container_print(const struct container *c, FILE *out)
{
    fwrite(c->content, 1, c->count, out);
}
```

---

Deletion:

```
int container_deleterange(struct container *c, size_t start, size_t n)
{
    if (start >= c->count || n > c->count || start + n > c->count)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    memmove(c->content + start, c->content + start + n,
            c->count - start - n);
    c->count -= n;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Disclaimer: Code might still contain bugs, wrote it directly here. It's just to demonstrate a possible approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a linked list of vectors.  Each vector in the list may have a different size.  For most applications, the first chunk should be small and optimized for short strings, and subsequent chunks should allocate a multiple of the system page size.

**Append:** O(1) time.  If you run out of space in the last chunk, allocate a new chunk.  Note that, for a simple dynamic array, this becomes O(n) because the entire array might need to be reallocated and copied to a new location.

**Print:** O(n) time. Print each chunk in the list in order.

**Delete:** Finding the range takes O(n) time in theory (It would be O(log n) with a rope or cord.) but in practice, strings won’t normally contain a large number of chunks. The remaining operations take O(1) time. If the range being deleted covers an entire chunk, delete it.  If it overlaps the end of one a chunk, truncate the chunk. If it overlaps the beginning of a chunk, C allows you to use a pointer within the chunk as a string, so just skip the deleted characters with pointer arithmetic.  If your chunks are smaller than 64KiB, the offset could be an `unsigned short` to save a few bytes of memory.  (You will still need to keep track of the original pointer to the memory block in order to `free()` it.)

Note that, for a single dynamic array, deleting a range in the middle requires array-shifting.

Another advantage is that concatenating a temporary string is also an O(1) time operation, and even copying and splicing become fast if you use smart pointers to your chunks.

If you needed to insert arbitrary characters in the middle, you might instead want a [rope or cord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(computer_science)).

Comment: "*this becomes O(n) because the entire array might need to be reallocated and copied to a new location.*" <- no it doesn't, except in a worst-case scenario with a fragmented heap. Sure this *can* happen.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The definition of O(n) is worst-case scenario. Granted, if each reallocation is nice and big, this will happen rarely. But, in a realtime application, you do care about the worst case.

Comment: no it isn't ... it's upper bound of exponent, which is something different. In this case (memory allocation), complexity depends on the previous state of the heap. With a freshly started process on a typical implementation, continuously reallocating the same chunk is O(1).

Comment: @FelixPalmieri If there's a worst case where you need to move the entire array to a different location, the time complexity is O(n). You might be thinking of some related definition, maybe average-case running time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a linked list of variable length strings is that you will invariably get zero-value (hex 00) as part of your string if you’re talking to a device , and the zero byte will terminate the string .  A linked list containing exactly one uint8_t value within each element, or related structure in the list , solves this problem.  Otherwise you’ll have all sorts of problems with the occasional (or non occasional) byte received as a zero-value.

Answer (score 0):

I use a linked list of chunks, starting with a capacity of 16 bytes and doubling each time to a maximum capacity of 1048576 bytes.  The idea there is to adapt as the code discovers that you're buffering more and more characters.

https://github.com/chkoreff/Fexl/blob/master/src/buffer.c

The code does not address your deletion requirement, as I am using it to implement a functional programming language where I don't need mutable strings.  But you could implement deletion by simply copying all the characters you want to keep into a new buffer.  You can even change the top level pointer so it appears mutable in place.